# What's best practice for mocking new method on different class

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have next scenario:

```
module Module
  class CommandPattern
    def initialize(value)
      command = []
      @var = value['something']
      @abc = value['abc']
      @command << value
    end

    def add(value)
      @command << value
    end

    def get_command
      @command
    end
  end
end

module Module
  class Implementator
    def initialize(value)
      @value = value
    end

    def method_to_test(argument)

      var = "command1"
      cmd = CommandPattern.new(var)
      var2 = "command2"
      cmd.add(var2)
      var3 = argument
      cmd.add(var3)

      commands = var + var2 + var3
      commands
    end
  end
end
```

So, when I'm testing Module::B.method_I_want_to_test, what would be the best practice to mock "var = A.new(some_stuff)"? Beside refactoring and moving this line into separate method, is there some nice way to do this?

Little bit of background on this question - this style (Module::ClassA and Module::ClassB) - I'm using http://naildrivin5.com/gli/ and reason for this approach is that class A is actually implementing Command Pattern.

So issue I was apparently getting was due to wrong way of trying to write specs.

What I did before was (on the way how @spickermann advised):

```
RSpec.describe Module::Implementator do

  describe "#method_to_test" do
    let(:command_argument)       { "command" }
    let(:cmnd)     { double(CommandPattern, :new => command_argument, :add => command_argument)}

    subject(:method_to_test) do
      Implementator.new("value").method_to_test("dejan")
    end

    before do
      allow(CommandPattern).to receive(:new).with(any_args).and_return(cmnd)
      allow(CommandPattern).to receive(:add).with(any_args).and_return(cmnd)
    end

    it 'does something' do
      expect{ method_to_test }.not_to raise_error
    end

    it 'does something else' do
      result = method_to_test
      expect(result).to eq("command1command2dejan")
    end
  end
end
```

Issue was apparently in testing Module::Implementator, didn't realise I can put module around my RSpec.describe block and solve my first issue:

```
module Module
  RSpec.describe Implementator do

  describe "#method_to_test" do
    let(:command_argument)       { "command" }
    let(:cmnd)     { double(CommandPattern, :new => command_argument, :add => command_argument)}

    subject(:method_to_test) do
      Implementator.new("value").method_to_test("dejan")
    end

    before do
      allow(CommandPattern).to receive(:new).with(any_args).and_return(cmnd)
      allow(CommandPattern).to receive(:add).with(any_args).and_return(cmnd)
    end

    it 'does something' do
      expect{ method_to_test }.not_to raise_error
    end

    it 'does something else' do
      result = method_to_test
      expect(result).to eq("command1command2dejan")
    end
  end

  end
end
```

Another issue I had was global variable keeping YAML structure, which I missed to see and declare in spec_helper.rb

However, thank's to @spickermann's advices, issue is solved.

Comment: Did you try rspec-mocks gem?

Comment: I did, but didn't have too much success so far. Can you point me to some specific example of what from rspec-mocks should be useful in this specific case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

```
describe '#method_I_want_to_test' do
  let(:something) { # whatever something needs to be }
  let(:a)         { double(A, # methods you need from a) }

  subject(:method_I_want_to_test) do
    B.new(something).method_I_want_to_test
  end

  before do
    allow(A).to receive(:new).with(something).and_return(a)
  end

  it 'does what I expect' do
    expect(method_I_want_to_test).to eq(# what do_semething_else returns)
  end
end
```

The interesting part is the `before` block that stubs the `new` method on `A`. It returns always the double defined in the `let(:a)` line instead of a real instance of `A`

Comment: I'm close, but I think I hit now different issue, as looks like problem is that both classes are inside (same module). So I have something like:

RSpec.describe Module::B do
.
.
.
end 

and within it spec code, but inside B method I want to test I have var = A.new(some_stuff) (not Module::A.new...) and looks like it's failing somewhere around here right now. Will try to fix this tomorrow morning when I'm maybe less tired. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So far still receiving expected no Exception, got #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass> with backtrace: for this part... Ok, now really continuing tomorrow morning :)

Comment: @DejanMenges : Your example does not have a `[]` method. I advise to open a new question for that this problem. The example in this question was perhaps over-simplified, try to post code that is a bit more expressive and looks more like your real code.

Comment: Solved it, I had couple of issues. Will explain it tomorrow with better code and test example and what was the issue in my case. Thanks a lot, you helped more then you probably think you do (I don't know why I didn't see [] method missing too, maybe just had too much for today).

Comment: Updated question and updated solution as well. Thanks a lot for help once again with approach how to do this best way!